# Deploying python apps to Cloud Foundry / Heroku and avoding the pip bug

Tags: python, heroku, pip, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

There's a [running UNICODE bug on PIP](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1137) that's blocking some people to use pip to deploy some packages as matplotlib or numpy.

When installing those packages manually, people is [patching pip](https://github.com/remram44/pip/commit/9626970115e2482e556f48896b7dfdf5e0e00d9e) to avoid this error, but when deploying on PAAS services as Heroku, BlueMix or any Cloud Foundry providers, it seems like you don't have that option, and cannot deploy my apps.

- How can I do that?
- Can I mark on my requirements file an
  external/different patched pip?

Comment: Hi Andor, PythonAnywhere dev here-- just wanted to let you know that we offer a PAAS specifically for python frameworks and do not have this problem. We do have the python-dev headers installed and also have a lot of the packages (eg: numpy as mentioned in the bug report) preinstalled.

Comment: Thanks Conrad, although I have to deploy this specific project in a Cloud Foundry target, I'll test your service for any future or current ones ;)

Comment: Is this still a problem for you?  How would I replicate this?  I tried running a Python app on Cloud Foundry that uses pip to install matplotlib, but it doesn't seem to create the problem you mentioned.  I have some ideas for workaround, but would need to test before I recommend anything.

Comment: @Andor could you please accept an answer?